# Partially Fill SVG icon using Css

Tags: css, svg, icons, fill

Is it possible to fill an svg icon partially based on some values?
use case : Star Rating

```css
svg{
fill: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
  <body>

    <!-- example icon -->
    <i data-feather="star"></i>
     <i data-feather="star"></i>
      <i data-feather="star"></i>

    <script>
      feather.replace()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't directly edit the original path, you could manipulate the dom of the SVG to insert a gradient tag with an ID, then reference it in the CSS with `fill : url(#gradient);`. It seems a bit hacky but it works :

```css
svg.full {
  fill:red;
}

svg#half {
  fill : url(#gradient);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- example icon -->
    <i class="full" data-feather="star"></i>
    <i id="half" data-feather="star"></i>
    <i data-feather="star"></i>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      feather.replace();
      
      // create the defs SVG tag
      // it is important to use createElementNS in that case
      const defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'defs');
      defs.innerHTML = '<linearGradient id="gradient"><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#F00"></stop><stop offset="50%" stop-color="transparent" ></stop></linearGradient>';
      
      // Here I'm targeting only the middle start by ID
      // You should modify the code to target all half-stars
      document.getElementById('half').append(defs);
      
    </script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

**PS** : By playing with the `<stop>` tags attribute's, you could achieve some original effects.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it in ONE SVG**

- I ditched the Font-Awesome icon
- searched for "star" in the 7000+ icons on https://iconmeister.github.io/ (first load takes a minute)
- Picked the star icon with the **best d-path** (Clarity Iconset: `cl-social-star-solid`)
- copied **only the d-path**
- Edited the d-path in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ to a **100x100**
  viewBox/grid
- made it an **inverse** star by prepending `M0 0h100v100h-100v-100` to the path
- Created a new SVG file in a `0 0 300 100` viewBox to fit 3 stars.. see below
- Added a **background rectangle** setting **gold** color rating with `width="50%"`
- Used **3** inverse stars, each at an x-offset
- added **6 rectangles** ***covering*** all half-stars
- set inline events on every "half-star"
  (the click works in this SO snippet, but SO adds a long delay)

#### Proof of Concept

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" width="500px">
  <rect id="rating" width="50%" fill="gold" height="100%" />

  <path id="star" fill="green" 
        d="M0 0h100v100h-100v-100m91 42a6 6 90 00-4-10l-22-1a1 1 90 01-1 
           0l-8-21a6 6 90 00-11 0l-8 21a1 1 90 01-1 1l-22 1a6 6 90 00-4 
           10l18 14a1 1 90 010 1l-6 22a6 6 90 008 6l19-13a1 1 90 011 0l19
           13a6 6 90 006 0a6 6 90 002-6l-6-22a1 1 90 010-1z"/>
    <use href="#star" x="100" />
    <use href="#star" x="200" />

  <rect id="c" width="16.66%" height="100%" fill="transparent" stroke="red" 
        onclick="console.log(this)" />
    <use href="#c" x="50" />
    <use href="#c" x="100" />
    <use href="#c" x="150" />
    <use href="#c" x="200" />
    <use href="#c" x="250" />
</svg>
```

## A Star Rating Component `<star-rating stars=N >`

You don't want to create all this SVG by hand... couple lines of JavaScript can create the SVG, for any number of stars

Using a **W3C standard Web Component** here, because it runs in this page and is not as complex as a React Component.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

- Not using `<use>`, just duplicate all paths and rects with a `x` offset
- mouseover events set the background % color
- click shows the index of the clicked halfstar (0+)
- Rating can be set with values **or** percentage; `document.querySelector('[stars="5"]').rating="90%"`  (4.5 stars)
- might needs extra work for your use case

#### All required HTML & JavaScript:

```html
<star-rating stars=5 rating="3.5"
             bgcolor="green" nocolor="grey" color="gold"></star-rating>
<star-rating stars=7 rating="50%"
             bgcolor="rebeccapurple" nocolor="beige" color="goldenrod"></star-rating>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => console.log(evt.target.getAttribute("n")))

  customElements.define("star-rating", class extends HTMLElement {
    set rating( rate ) {
      if (!String(rate).includes("%")) rate = Number(rate) / this.stars * 100 + "%";
      this.querySelector("#rating").setAttribute("width", rate);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let { bgcolor, stars, nocolor, color, rating } = this.attributes;
      this.stars = ~~stars.value || 5;
      this.innerHTML = 
        `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${this.stars*100} 100" style="cursor:pointer;width:300px">`
      + `<rect width="100%" height="100" fill="${nocolor.value}"/>`
      + `<rect id="rating"  height="100" fill="${color.value}"  />`
        + Array(  this.stars     ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<path fill="${bgcolor.value}" d="M${ n*100 } 0h102v100h-102v-100m91 42a6 6 90 00-4-10l-22-1a1 1 90 01-1 0l-8-21a6 6 90 00-11 0l-8 21a1 1 90 01-1 1l-22 1a6 6 90 00-4 10l18 14a1 1 90 010 1l-6 22a6 6 90 008 6l19-13a1 1 90 011 0l19 13a6 6 90 006 0a6 6 90 002-6l-6-22a1 1 90 010-1z"/>`)
               .join("")
        + Array(  this.stars * 2 ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<rect x="${ n*50 }" n="${n}" opacity="0" width="50" height="100"`
                  + ` onclick="dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))" `
                  + ` onmouseover="this.closest('star-rating').rating = ${(n+1)/2}"/>`)
              .join("") 
      + "</svg>";

      this.rating = rating.value;
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Notes**:

- This **native** `<star-rating>` Component (also called ***Custom Element*** because NO shadowDOM is involved) has **ZERO dependencies**

  - no libraries
  - no external SVG
- native components are not self-closing tags and must contain a hyphen, so notation is: `<star-rating></star-rating>`
- Changed the star to `M0 0h102v100h-102v-100` (2 pixel overlap) to cover SVG rounding issues

#### Supported in all Frameworks... except...

React doesn't support this modern W3C Web Components **Standard** yet.

React scores just **71%** on https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

All other Frameworks (Angular, Vue, Svelte) have **100%** support

You have to do some extra work to handle native DOM Elements and Events in React; but the Custom Element isn't complex.. it creates SVG; should be easy to replicate as a React Component.